# Delete data from database not working in broadcast receiver in Android

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I am deleting data from database when app is closed. So I open broadcast receiver onDestroy and delete data inside receiver. When I call delete method of database helper inside Activity, it is working. But when I call it inside receiver, it is not working.

This is my receiver:

```
public class InspectDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    }

    public void refreshData(final Context context,String type)
    {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        dbHelper.deleteCategories();

    } }
```

This is delete method of database helper:

```
public void deleteCategories()
    {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(CATEGORY_TABLE,null,null);
        db.close();
    }
```

This is how I delete data in the onDestroy event of my activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        updateCacheData();
    }

    private void updateCacheData()
    {
        InspectDataReceiver receiver = new InspectDataReceiver();
        receiver.refreshData(getBaseContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.data_receiver_type_category));
    }
```

But data are not deleted.It is not throwing error as well. When I delete within activity. Delete method is working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not doing anything inside `onReceive()`, you need to call `refreshData()`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    refreshData(context);
}
```

or call `deleteCategories()` method directly:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    dbHelper.deleteCategories();
}
```

in second case you dont need to define `refreshData()` in the receiver class

Comment: But how can I pass context of activity when I open receiver?

Comment: This isn't going to work. The OP isn't actually using their `BroadcastReceiver` class as a `BroadcastReceiver`. That is, they're not actually broadcasting to it. They could do exactly what they're doing now with a plain old class that doesn't extend anything.

Comment: @MikeM. opps, just noted that, OP creates instance of the receiver

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found a way by your answer. I called onReceive method inside refreshData method.